# Zabbix bandwidth monitoring

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth, zabbix

How can I collect network bandwidth on the network interface for a month?Is it possible to get data by zabbix tools? One of the main problems is to set up period for monitoring. I create calculated item that get traffic for a minute and I try to   sum it by function "sum(total.traffic[{#IFNAME}],30d)", but it returns me value for  the last 30 days. How can I set up some period that will return sum of values from beginning of month to nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is that you use `vnstat`

Here you have everything

[monthly Bandwidth in Zabbix](https://github.com/vishneak/Zabbix-Monthly-Bandwith)

Comment: I agree with you, It is one of the most comfortable way for monitoring on Linux servers, but what about Windows servers?

Comment: hard with windows :) have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=win10-ps